# Visual Basic: Best way to share data/variables over network?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, networking

My Visual Basic project involves two applications (server and client if you will). The "Server" gathers data from a sensor and the Client must somehow get this information and display it.

My question is:
Whats the best way to get the data from the server to the client? The first thing that comes to my mind is storing the information in an SQL DB and the "client" will pull the data from the DB.

It is worth noting the "Server" and "Client" will eventually be networked through a WAN and NAT...

The data from the sensor is very small, i.e two separate integers, that's it. So an SQL DB seems like overkill to store two integers in. Plus the hardware i'm running these on will not be very powerful, i.e, 1gb ram and 2ghz CPU.

Thanks :)

Comment: Store the data in a file in a network share accessible by both parties?

Comment: I did think of that, I would have to setup some kind of FTP service on the "Server" or a VPN between the "Server" and "Client" to use a CIFS share as they are not on the same LAN. They are on separate NATed WANs...

I was hoping for something a little more elegant.

Thanks for the idea tho

Comment: Generally speaking, when a question begins _What's the best way..._ it will likely get closed for being too broad.  As to your question, does the Server run continuously?  You could try hosting a simple WCF service or use named pipes.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not sensitive and you don't mind it being publicly accessible, the server could run a small web server (IIS or something similar) and write the data to a file on that web server.

The client would then download the file by simply visiting that web address and parsing the file.

If you need a level of authentication, you could store the data in a file which is not publicly accessible and then write an asp/asp.net page which accepts a HTTP Post containing a password and then returns reads the file and sends it as a response.

Answer (score 0):

I have decide to try a P2P connection between the "Server" and "Client", This seems to be working a a LAN but Im yet to test it through a NAT. Obviously I will have to do some basic port forwarding to get this to work.